# How to put multiple match query inside a bool query in elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, java

I am trying to implement below elasticsearch query

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {"match": {"collegeName": "XXXX"}},
            {"match": {"userType": "STUDENT"}},
            {"match": {"details.blocklisted":"TRUE"}}
            ]
    }
}
```

}

How do I implement it in java.
I thought of doing this

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder.must(new 
MatchQueryBuilder("collegeName",loggedInUserCollegeName)).must(new MatchQueryBuilder("userType",studentsSearchRequestDTO.getUserType())).must(new MatchQueryBuilder("details.blocklisted",studentsSearchRequestDTO.isBlockListed())));
```

Is there a better way to do????
Help!!

Answer (score 2):

you can use `MultiMatchQueryBuilder` something like

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
              .withQuery(multiMatchQuery("college")
                .field("collegeName")
                .field("userType")
                .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.BEST_FIELDS))
              .build();
```

Comment: i'm trying to use multiMatchQuery but this method is not found

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Use Search Template ([ES official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html)). It's like a stored procedure. A query with a replaceable variable. Plus changing the query is just a simple update. Create template beforehand (POST /_search/template/templateName {BODY} ) then you can call it (POST /twitter/tweet/_search/templateName {BODY containing dynamic variables}).

similarly in JAVA

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("search_term", "elasticsearch");
params.put("since", "now-30d");

Template template = new Template("tweets", ScriptService.ScriptType.FILE, 
MustacheScriptEngineService.NAME, null, params);
SearchRequestBuilder request = 
client.prepareSearch(INDEX).setTemplate(template);
```

SearchResponse response = request.execute().actionGet();